# Particle images in unity have corners?

Tags: unity-game-engine, particle-system

I cant find any post on this anywhere else - I have created a particle system in unity, and Ive gotten my own image in by assigning it to a material. My problem is since my image is a circle, when the particles overlap one can see the corners of the image cutting into the other particle.

[image]

This is my material:

[image]

How can I stop this?

Comment: It's something about the shader you're using. Try changing it to Transparent one, or modifying your custom one.

Comment: Your problem is likely that your particles are writing to the ZDepth buffer (based on the name of that shader) which *includes the transparent pixels* unless the shader handles it properly (which it is clearly not doing). If you post the shadercode being used, then it will be possible to disect it to figure out why it's not doing what you expect it to do. e.g. is it tagged for the Transparent queue (or opaque?), what's its alpha blend function, is ZWrite turned on, etc. I'd be more than happy to look it over and post an actual answer.